# How to map excel keywords to their specific folders?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, windows-explorer, microsoft-office, user-folders

I have a list of supermarket items in excel say 6000 products for example. I run a software which takes one product name at a time and performs a google search, and then downloads the most relevant image for that particular keyword and places it in a sub-folder created using the same keyword name as the folder name.  The Software i run does not always return back with the same number of product list(As some images of products are not found). Approximately for 6000 products, 5800 product images are downloaded.

My Question here is "Is there a way to get these sub-folders to match with their respective keyword in the excel sheet, so that i know which images haven't been downloaded"?

**Check out the PICS :-**

[This is the Excel List for Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XabJq.png)

[These are the Images in sub-folders with the same keyword as excel name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAoe3.png)

Comment: You need method (Macro) to get file names from folder to Excel sheet to match with existing names.

Comment: Other option besides macros would be to create a list of all folders and match them to current list using formula (e.g. MATCH).

Comment: I am a noob and dont know what is a macro and how to implement macro and Match, can you guys please help me step by step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start > type "cmd" > Run .  Then navigate to your pics folder using cd or cd ..

when you reached the folder, type `dir` to verify the content is the same as the folder view link you shared.

if it is correct, type in : `dir /a:d /b > foldername.txt`

then using notepad, open the newly created "foldername.txt" file (in the same folder), or you may type `notepad foldername.txt` directly to open it.

Once opened, copy all the listed folder names to `B2` cell of your excel file .

Assuming there is 6000 products (in column A) , type this in `C2`, and drag it until `C6001`.

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,A2)
```

If the value is 1, there is a folder created. If 0, then no folder is created.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Buddy, everything worked well until the last part, when i Copied 5300 folder names in Column B next to 6000 keyword names. Firstly the keyword and the Folder Names dint match as 700 keywords are missing and secondly since Column B ends at 5300. Every value after 5300 gives 0 as Column B is empty after 5300.

Comment: sorry.. error in the formula.. it should be `=COUNTIF(B:B,A2)` instead. My bad. :|